# Is there a fast way to disable controls for non-authorized users in ASP.net MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I want to disable some controls on my views for non-authorized users. What is the fastest way to implement this in my views.

I'm implementing an ASP.net MVC 4 application - Razor view - Internet Application template.

The problem is that I want to disable an ActionLink:

```
<td>
      @Html.ActionLink("Register", "SetRegisteredStatus", new { id = item2.Id })
</td>
```

Comment: What kind of controls do you have? Home baked or from the third-party vendor (e.g. Telerik)?

Comment: Are you using `Roles`?

Comment: @volpav My controls are all Home baked

Comment: @christiandev I selected Internet Application template - I'm not sure how to reply.

Comment: @BadaBoom, well, how are you distinguishing between user authorization? do you have some kind of User Level, e.g. **AdminRole**, **SomePermissionsRole**, **ReadOnlyRole** etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the action link, try...

```
@if (User.IsInRole("AllowedToSetRegisteredStatusRole"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Register", "SetRegisteredStatus", new { id = item2.Id })
}
```

Take a look at this link for how to use a [`Custom roles Provider`](http://bojanskr.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/custom-role-provider.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know if the user has actually logged in and authenticated themselves with the site then you can use the [IsAuthenticated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.isauthenticated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property e.g.

```
<input id="control" @(Page.User.IsAuthenticated ? "disabled='true'" : "") />
```

If you are using roles, you can use (assuming you are using the default Membership Role Provider) you can use [IsInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.isinrole%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) e.g.

```
<input id="control" @(!Page.User.IsInRole("admin") ? "disabled='true'" : "") />
```

Outwith those approaches you are really looking at something custom, perhaps just passing the information down with the view model itself or an extension method on `Page.User` if you are using custom authentication/authorization mechanisms.

Comment: I think OP wants to know if the user is Authorized to use the control.

Comment: @christiandev I took *"non-authorized"* in a vague context, considering the OP asked the question in one (no info on what *"non-authorized"* actually means).